# Send big size file using HttpPost android in bytes

Tags: android, http

Hi all I am able to send file upto 1.3 mb using HttpPost and file is sending from the service of android to php server.

this way i did
http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/android-http-downlod-upload-multipart.html

**showing buffering only in logcat**

Comment: you can use multipart post

Comment: But what is your question? Or problem?

Comment: I am not able to send file above 1.43 mb , and there is no error showing on Logcat.